# postman: save response on a global variable

Tags: postman

With PostMan, how can  save the follow response:

```
[
    {
        "id": "6254c754-5a97-43fd-9b48-c428b9bd69e5",
        "name": "fdsfds",
        "description": "fdzf",
        "type": 0,
        "createDate": "2018-08-01T17:49:29.071+01:00",
        "lastUpdateDate": "2018-08-01T17:49:29.071+01:00",
        "lastUpdateUser": null,
        "variables": null,
        "instructions": null
    }
]
```

on a variable? For example the id?

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

console.log(jsonData.id);

pm.globals.set("variable_key", jsonData.id);
```

Comment: try to stringify the whole array... pm.globals.set("array", JSON.Stringify(jsonData)); https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/scripts/test_examples

Comment: I convert it to string:


[{"id":"6254c754-5a97-43fd-9b48-c428b9bd69e5","name":"fdsfds","description":"fdzf","type":0,"createDate":"2018-08-01T17:49:29.071+01:00","lastUpdateDate":"2018-08-01T17:49:29.071+01:00","lastUpdateUser":null,"variables":null,"instructions":null}]

But only want to tach the id. i need the id for a delete

Answer (score 10):

to set the environment variable "authkey" from response

```
var obj = pm.response.json()["token"];
pm.environment.set("authkey", obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the response that I work with:

```
{id: "myId", version: "2.0", name: "test"…}
```

This is how I set the id value from the response into my global variable "appId":

```
var requestJson = JSON.parse(request.data);
console.log(requestJson)
postman.setGlobalVariable("appId", requestJson.id);
```

Result:

[image: result]

Answer (score 1):

You can't save JS Objects directly in a global variable but you can use JSON library to convert your object to string and save, like the following code:

```
// create the JS Object
var obj = {
    foo: "bar",
    some_number: 91
}

// convert the obj to string and save in the globals
pm.globals.set("my_obj", JSON.stringify(obj));

// get obj from globals and parse to JS Object again
var obj_from_globals = JSON.parse(pm.globals.get("my_obj"));

// print int he console
console.log(obj_from_globals);
```

You should expect this in your console:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think i resolve this with:

```
var jsonData = pm.response.json();

for (var key in jsonData) {
if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
var seqDelete = jsonData[key].id;
console.log(seqDelete);
}
}
pm.globals.set("seqDelete", seqDelete);
```

This isn´t totally correct.
If i have multidimension array, this only gets one ID value